# How to stop evolution-alarm-notify

Tags: gnome, notification, evolution, calendar

A few months ago, I started getting these pop-ups from evolution-alarm-notify. They are some kind of calendar reminder. But they are horribly inaccurate. They either don't reflect any changes I have made to calendar events or they include all previous versions of the events and may or may not include the current version of those events. And I can't seem to mark events as complete in the evolution-alarm-notify window.

I don't need these pop-ups and would prefer to just make them go away permanently.
I don't have the Evolution mail app installed, and can't find an evolution-alarm-notify app on my system.

So how do I get rid of evolution-alarm notify?

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

GNOME 3.36.8

Dell Precision 7740

Answer (score 20):

Notifications -> Evolution Alarms Notify -> Off

[image]

here's the repo if anyone wants to dig: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution

Comment: This seems lke its the best answer, as of May 2023.

Comment: Does not seem to work in Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: As effortless, common sense, and problem-free as nix likes to be, claims to be, and wants to be, this setting seems to be a fly in the ointment, but depending on your point of view it may actually be its teaching moment. ¶If programs leave settings enabled as a way to, uh, *force the user to learn that its features are available, they'll never be exposed to it and they'll never learn how rich *nix and its programs' feature sets are. ¶It's a good problem to have.

Comment: Neither works in Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: This still seems like the best answer, as of Nov 2023.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in 22.04

Answer (score 17):

You have to copy the `/etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.Evolution-alarm-notify.desktop` file to your home folder by

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart/
cp /etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.Evolution-alarm-notify.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/" ~/.config/autostart/org.gnome.Evolution-alarm-notify.desktop
```

and then disable its launch, either from `gnome-session-properties` (Startup Applications), or by adding a line with `Hidden=true` to the file. If you are using MATE, then use `mate-session-properties` instead of `gnome-session-properties`

Also disable its systemd user services:

```
systemctl --user mask evolution-addressbook-factory.service
systemctl --user mask evolution-calendar-factory.service
systemctl --user mask evolution-source-registry.service
systemctl --user mask evolution-user-prompter.service
```

and then reboot.

Comment: This appears to have worked!  Thanks, N0rbert!
It has been about a day and I have not seen a pop-up window.  
Though it also seems to have killed the notifications when I click on the date in the top bar. I do not care about these notifications enough to suffer the pop-up window. I do find it interesting that they are related though because the ones under the top bar were not plagued by the incorrect and out-of-date issues that the pop-up window had.  But if anyone else is looking at this as a solution, and loves their top bar notifications, this may not be the solution for you.

Comment: Do you know of a way to stop the notifications for the current session? (without disabling them)

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications.application:/org/gnome/desktop/notifications/application/org-gnome-evolution/ enable false` helps?

Comment: I have gnome-sessions available, but not gnome-session-properties. How can I disable launch on startup?

Comment: To disable autostart from the terminal, add a line to your `~/.config/autostart/org.gnome.Evolution-alarm-notify.desktop` containing `Hidden=true`, that will disable the file.

Comment: To only disable it for the current session, killing the `evolution-alarm-notify` process should be enough: `pkill evolution-alarm`. (Not tested as I don't have it running.)

Comment: If you only want  to disable the annoying popups, there is (I think, not yet tested) no need to disable the systemd services.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in Jay Schauer's comment over [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/295#:%7E:text=Open%20GNOME%20Settings,even%20though%20it%27s%20turned%20off.). The solution is to edit the file /etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.Evolution-alarm-notify.desktop

Change the line `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;XFCE;Dawati;MATE;` to `NotShowIn=GNOME;`

Log out and back in for the changes to take effect.

Comment: This disables the desktop file in the GNOME environment. To disable the file unconditionally, add a line with `Hidden=true`, that will disable the file in all desktop environments.

Comment: I have this file in 22.04 but it doesn't have this entry at all

Answer (score 3):

I looked at several sites (listed below) when trying to get rid of the Evolution reminders.

What worked for me was just deleting `~/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system/calendar.ics`

The file hasn’t been recreated, even after multiple reboots, and even though System Monitor still shows evolution-alarm-notify as up and running (along with the other three Evolution processes).

I haven’t needed to amend `/etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.Evolution-alarm-notify.desktop` (contents listed below).

I haven’t needed to uninstall the evolution-data-server package.

I’m running Thunderbird 102.11.0 (64-bit) under Linux Mint 21.1 Vera base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy.

`/etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.Evolution-alarm-notify.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Evolution Alarm Notify
Comment=Calendar event notifications
Icon=appointment-soon
Exec=/usr/libexec/evolution-data-server/evolution-alarm-notify
Terminal=false
Categories=
NoDisplay=true
X-Meego-Priority=Low
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=evolution-data-server
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=calendar
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.44.x
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=evolution-data-server
```

URLs:

- [How to stop evolution-alarm-notify](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317784/how-to-stop-evolution-alarm-notify?newreg=59ce4757752f480ea82d66afe39efff4)
  https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/295
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2471850
- https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=360882
- https://gist.github.com/anibalardid/8c87fb32d94c89326390045bb88e112a

Answer (score 0):

Open the evolution ui from the terminal with `evolution`. There you can disable the notifications easily

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).