# Ubuntu MATE 20.04 - How to remove Reminders indicator from panel

Tags: indicator, mate, panel, evolution

I tried out `evolution` and decided I didn't care for it. During the process this Reminders indicator appeared on the panel.

[image]

I've now uninstalled and purged `evolution` but I still have this, now non-functional indicator on the panel.

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Check my answer from similar topic at https://askubuntu.com/a/1317844/66509 . Use `mate-session-properties` at the end of first step.

Comment: @N0rbert it worked. Many thanks. +1 to that answer, and closing this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to copy the `/etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.Evolution-alarm-notify.desktop` file to your home folder by

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart/
cp /etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.Evolution-alarm-notify.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/" ~/.config/autostart/org.gnome.Evolution-alarm-notify.desktop
```

and then disable its launch from `mate-session-properties` (Startup Applications).

Also disable its systemd user services:

```
systemctl --user mask evolution-addressbook-factory.service
systemctl --user mask evolution-calendar-factory.service
systemctl --user mask evolution-source-registry.service
systemctl --user mask evolution-user-prompter.service
```

and then reboot.

Comment: Never in a million years would I have figured out to do this - creating a desktop just so I could disable it. This sort of answer is why Ask Ubuntu is invaluable.