# Proper way to disable Evolution services when it's purged already

Tags: services, ubuntu-mate, evolution, background-process

Though I have gone through quite a few threads on AskUbuntu, I couldn't find a proper way to disable these Evolution services, **especially when Evolution is purged from the system already**, in Ubuntu MATE 21.04.

These services are not listed under `systemctl list-unit-files --type=service`, so I can't use `sudo systemctl mask`.

```
ps -ef | grep evolution

admn 1973 1459 0 17:15 ? 00:00:00 /usr/libexec/evolution-source-registry
admn 2023 1459 0 17:15 ? 00:00:00 /usr/libexec/evolution-calendar-factory
admn 2058 1459 0 17:15 ? 00:00:00 /usr/libexec/evolution-addressbook-factory
```

These 2 Evolution related packages are still there, because purging them would remove a lot of other packages.

```
evolution-data-server
evolution-data-server-common
```

Result of `ls -lsh /usr/libexec/evolution*`:

```
$ ls -lsh /usr/libexec/evolution*

 16K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  15K Jun 22 20:57 /usr/libexec/evolution-addressbook-factory
 48K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  47K Jun 22 20:57 /usr/libexec/evolution-addressbook-factory-subprocess
116K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 115K Jun 22 20:57 /usr/libexec/evolution-calendar-factory
136K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 135K Jun 22 20:57 /usr/libexec/evolution-calendar-factory-subprocess
 60K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  59K Jun 22 20:57 /usr/libexec/evolution-scan-gconf-tree-xml
124K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 123K Jun 22 20:57 /usr/libexec/evolution-source-registry
 20K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  19K Jun 22 20:57 /usr/libexec/evolution-user-prompter

/usr/libexec/evolution-data-server:
total 116K

 32K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  31K Jun 22 20:57 addressbook-export
8.0K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7.0K Jun 22 20:57 csv2vcard
 52K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  51K Jun 22 20:57 evolution-alarm-notify
 24K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  23K Jun 22 20:57 list-sources
```

OS: Ubuntu MATE 21.04

evolution-data-server: 3.40.0-1ubuntu1.1

evolution-data-server-common: 3.40.0-1ubuntu1.1

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop evolution-alarm-notify](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317784/how-to-stop-evolution-alarm-notify)

Comment: @n0rbert As I have mentioned in my question, when I try: `systemctl status evolution-addressbook-factory.service`, I'm getting this message: `Unit evolution-calendar-factory.service could not be found.` Thanks.

Comment: You have to pass `--user` to `systemctl`. All these units are owned and started by user session.

Comment: @n0rbert Ahhh that's why I was not able to find these services. So I should just `systemctl --user mask` these 4 services: `evolution-addressbook-factory.service`, `evolution-calendar-factory.service`, `evolution-source-registry.service`, `evolution-user-prompter.service` or do I need to copy `.desktop` to `~/.config/autostart/` as mentioned in the link you've posted? Many thanks.

Comment: @n0rbert Also, would you like to post an answer please? Because the other thread you have mentioned is mainly about `evolution-alarm-notify`... the issue I do not have. I think an answer here would help any future visitor that because of the lack of `--user` to `systemctl` was the cause of not finding these services. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's start from the beginning. On the fresh Ubuntu MATE 21.04 I have:

```
$ ps -ef | grep evolution | grep -v grep
h           2025    1612  1 22:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/evolution-data-server/evolution-alarm-notify
h           2112    1595  1 22:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/evolution-source-registry
h           2230    1595  1 22:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/evolution-calendar-factory
h           2250    1595  1 22:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/evolution-addressbook-factory

$ systemctl list-units --type service --user | grep evolution
  evolution-addressbook-factory.service loaded active running Evolution address book service
  evolution-calendar-factory.service    loaded active running Evolution calendar service
  evolution-source-registry.service     loaded active running Evolution source registry
```

To disable parts of Evolution Data Server one should disable systemd user services by:

```
systemctl --user mask evolution-addressbook-factory.service
systemctl --user mask evolution-calendar-factory.service
systemctl --user mask evolution-source-registry.service
systemctl --user mask evolution-user-prompter.service
```

and reboot.

If you want to take radical measures then use below command

```
sudo apt autopurge evolution-data-server
```

to remove the package providing above systemd units.

---

Also please note that removing of remaining three packages named `evolution-data-server-common`, `libecal-2.0-1:amd64` and `libedataserver-1.2-26:amd64` will remove `ayatana-indicator-datetime`. So the resulting system will not have Calendar on the MATE Panel. Do not remove these 3 packages listed above.

Comment: `systemctl --user mask` 4 services solves the issue. For now, I'm not purging `evolution-data-server` or other 3 packages you have listed, as I do want to keep `ayatana-indicator-datetime` working in MATE. As always thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Evolution-data-server (EDS) was --long ago-- an outgrowth of Evolution. However, EDS is not part of Evolution; they are separate. Only the name remains.

EDS is part of a stock install of Ubuntu, and should remain on your system whether or not you choose to install or use Evolution.

EDS handles your unified calendar and addressbook for the for your Desktop session. Most Desktop users should leave it in place and let it do its job.

Comment: I'm sorry to say your answer narrowly focuses on Evolution name and does not focus on disabling three services I have listed in my question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sory but you said, "Most Desktop users should leave it in place and let it do its job."... if that was the case.. I would be using Microsoft Windows.

Comment: Most folks who ask this kind of question are confused. They think the services are part of the Evolution groupware suite. They are not. Then the same folks get all frizzed up when applications can't find the calendars and contacts and other data they expected to be there. If you are not among that common set, you should edit your question to make clear that you fully understand the consequences of what you are asking for.

Comment: If my question is not "crystal clear" enough to you... I'm sorry I do not have to say anything further to you.

Comment: Okay. Have a nice day.